# What causes polarization current density in plasma?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

Plasma current density is defined as $\textbf{j}=-\mathrm{e}n_e\textbf{u}_e$ where $\mathrm{e}$ is electron charge, $n_e$ is electron concentration and $\textbf{u}_e$ is electron velocity. What exactly causes polarization current density and why we do not consider other types of current densities (free-charge current density, magnetization current density) in plasma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polarization current can be driven by something that causes a time-varying electric field, like a [gradient drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiding_center) which forces positive and negative charges to drift in opposite directions.  This can be similar to a [displacement current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current), but it is generally driven by bulk particle motion.

**Side Note:**
The [current density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density) is not just due to the electron drift.  Currents are also not a [Lorentz invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_covariance).  The current density in the macroscopic sense is defined by:
$$
\mathbf{j} = \sum_{s} \ n_{s} \ q_{s} \ \mathbf{v}_{s}
$$
where $n_{s}$ is the [number density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_density), $q_{s}$ is the [electric charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge), and $\mathbf{v}_{s}$ is the [bulk flow velocity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/218418/visualising-gas-temperature-and-gas-pressure/218643#218643) of particle species $s$.  So as you can see, the current density is not just derived from the electron flow, though electrons often do carry currents due to their higher mobility than ions.

Comment: So do all drifts such as gradient drift, gravitational drift, curvature drift or  polarization drift cause the polarization current? Or should we say it is the conduction current? What is the difference?

Comment: I see the confusion, yes...  So the conduction current is generally just associated with bulk charge motion and quasi-static magnetic fields.  An example of a polarization current is plasma at rest in a gravitational field above a neutral atmosphere.  If the gravitational field is orthogonal to the quasi-static magnetic field, the resulting drifts will cause local charge separations, thus a polarization electric field (which is time-varying).  The relative drift of these particles is an example of a polarization current.

Comment: Note that polarization currents are similar to the conduction current in that they involve bulk particle motions but they are generally associated with changing electric flux.