# Why is the average thermal velocity 0?

Tags: electricity, statistical-mechanics, electric-current

Thermal velocity is the velocity of the free electron due to their random motion. So how is the average value 0?

Comment: why should a free electron be more likely to be moving left than right?

Comment: @BySymmetry I love how your username perfectly fits your comment :-P

Comment: Gupta ji , If it was not 0, your object will run out of electrons.

Comment: I think you are confusing the _average velocity_ (i.e., first [velocity moments](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218643/59023)) with the _thermal speed_ (i.e., can be from the second velocity moment with some assumptions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their average *speed* would be non zero but their average *velocity* would be zero as long as they are not moving preferentially in one direction.