# How to calculate the RMS speed of plasma?

Tags: thermodynamics, plasma-physics

I know the RMS (root mean square) speed of gas is calculated with $v = \sqrt{\frac{3RT}M}$, and plasma is very similar to gas, so is there a difference? If so, how do you calculate it?

Comment: See my answer to these related questions:  [http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023) and [http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218643/59023](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218643/59023).