# On the way Feynman derived the velocity distribution of a gas in thermal equilibrium

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, ideal-gas, kinetic-theory

In Feynman's treatment of [statistical mechanics](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_40.html), $40–4$ *The distribution of molecular speeds*, Feynman analyzes a gas at thermal equilibrium, and derives the distribution of the velocity of its molecules, he writes,

> Let us count how many molecules are passing from below to above the plane $h=0$ (by calling it height$=0$, we do not mean that there is a floor there; it is just a convenient label, and there is gas at negative h). These gas molecules are moving around in every direction, but some of them are moving through the plane, and at any moment a certain number per second of them are passing through the plane from below to above with different velocities. Now we note the following: if we call $u$ the velocity which is just needed to get up to the height $h$ (kinetic energy $mu^{2}/2=mgh$), then the number of molecules per second which are passing upward through the lower plane in a vertical direction with velocity component greater than $u$ is exactly the same as the number which pass through the upper plane with any upward velocity. Those molecules whose vertical velocity does not exceed $u$ cannot get through the upper plane. So therefore we see that
> $$\begin{equation*}
> \text{Number passing }h = 0
> \text{ with }v_z > u =
> \text{number passing }h = h
> \text{ with }v_z > 0.
> \end{equation*}$$

[image]

> But the number which pass through $h$ with any velocity greater than $0$ is less than the number which pass through the lower height with any velocity greater than $0$, because the number of atoms is greater; that is all we need. We know already that the distribution of velocities is the same, after the argument we made earlier about the temperature being constant all the way through the atmosphere. So, **since the velocity distributions are the same**, and it is just that there are more atoms lower down, **clearly** the number $n_{>0}(h)$, passing with positive velocity at height $h$, and the number $n_{>0}(0)$, passing with positive velocity at height $0$, **are in the same ratio as the densities at the two heights**, which is $e^{−mgh/kT}$. But $n_{>0}(h)=n_{>u}(0)$, and therefore we find that
>
> $$\begin{equation*}
> \frac{n_{> u}(0)}{n_{> 0}(0)} =
> e^{-mgh/kT} = e^{-mu^2/2kT},
> \end{equation*}$$

$\\$

As he mentioned it, the density of the gas, which he derived two sections before, is $n(h)=n_{0}e^{-mgh/kT}$, where $h$ is the height and $n_{0}$ is the density at $h=0$.

Even under the assumption that the velocity distribution is homogeneous, which he didn't really give a proof for, why is it that the ratio $n_{> 0}(h) /n_{> 0}(0)$ must be the same as the density ratio, which is equal to $e^{-mgh/kT}$?

Comment: I balked at exactly the same paragraph, for the same reason (or absence thereof.)  I attempted my own remedy, discussed here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/399772/117014 I haven't reviewed it carefully of late, but I don't believe my solution is sufficiently rigorous.  As a hand-waving argument, we might simply assume the velocity (as opposed to speed) distribution https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_40.html#Ch40-F5 should be Gaussian unless otherwise determined.  But I'm guessing.

Comment: This reliable introductory source apparently gives the homogeneity of the distribution as a primary assumption (AKA axiom).  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hframe.html  My hand-waving the Gaussian distribution is circular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding the homogeneity of velocity distribution, you may want to consider what would happen if a different distribution was present at different heights. His argument is that velocity distribution is independent of how many particles are subject to it, and only depends on the type of particles and the temperature of the system. The former is obviously the same, and he argues that for thermal equilibrium conditions we need $\forall z\ T(z)=T_0$, thus the velocity distribution must be the same everywhere.

Now assuming what is written above is correct, let's try to build the $n_{>0}(z)$ from this certain constant velocity distribution for velocity in $z$ direction, $p_{z}(v_z;z)=p_{z}(v_z;0)$.

It is evident that at if at height $z$ the total density is $n(z)$, the density of particles going upward is simply
$$n_{>0}(z) = \int_0^\infty n(z)\,p_z(v_z;z)\,dv_z = n(z)\,\int_0^\infty p_z(v_z;0)\,dv_z$$

where the second equality follows from the previous equation. Notice that $n_{>0}(z)$ is directly proportional to $n(z)$ regardless of the actual physics of the thermal equilibrium so long as it is in thermal equilibrium. Rest of the argument follows as you cited.

Comment: I understand that the average velocity squared is proportional to the temperature, and that if we have a constant temperature throughout the gas, then the $\overline{v}^{2}$ must be the same everywhere. That's as far as we can get, I think, with the thermal equilibrium assumption. And the independence of the distribution from the number of particles is also not that obvious: the number of collisions per second increases with the increase of the number of particles per unit volume, doesn't this have an effect on $p_{z}(v_{z},z)$?

Comment: @Hilbert In its essence, statistical mechanics argue that we can tie the behavior of a system to the mean behavior of its constituents. Since what a particle does (in most models including Maxwell-Boltzmann, B-E, and F-D) is **independent from what is happening to the others**, particle count and density is irrelevant. If the model of a single particle depended on how the other particles are behaving, it would lose its simplicity, which is why we use models in the first place.

Comment: @acarturk I came up with exactly the same question regarding Feynman's argument that velocity distribution is independent of density.  I really don't understand how your answer addresses that question.  You seem to be saying it has to be that way because any alternative would be too complicated to understand.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Non-interaction means there is no venue for other particles to affect any other particle. The argument in my previous comment holds as long as you assume non-interacting particles, an assumption I was trying to justify by saying it's for simplicity. So non-interaction implies $v$ distribution is not dependent on density, however it doesn't say it's not correlated to it, nor independent of other variables (such as potential energy), even though it turns out that it _is_ independent from them as well.