# Radial dependence of temperature for adiabatic expansion of ideal gas

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, plasma-physics, adiabatic

If the solar wind propagates out adiabatically with a constant speed and
can be regarded as an ideal gas, how the solar wind temperature depend
on radial distance from the sun $r$, i.e. $T$ as a function of $T(r)$?

Comment: Wellcome @Tasnim, you say that the solar wind is constant but you ask for its dependence on the radius. Do you mean that the velocity is not an explicit function of time?

Comment: Thank you. It is assumed that the solar wind propagates radially with a constant speed (adiabatic) from the sun.  The main focus of this question is radial dependence of temperature for the adiabatic process.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/695955/59023

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could be of use for your problem, but the ideal gas with a homogeneous gravity field is well known classical problem of statistical physics. It induces a non-homogeneous concentration of particles.

For this result, you can visit problems 6.8 and 6.10 of Patrhia's statistical mechanics book.

I don't know how to add the "solar wind" to this solution. But in any case, the Hamiltonian would be the same, right? Wouldn't it just be a matter of adding a [Gallilean transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_transformation) to the result?