# Paper about solar wind model

Tags: plasma-physics, solar-system, solar-wind

I am searching for a paper about the solar wind. In particular, I need a model (or real data) that describes plasma density as a function of time and location in space. Do such data exist in the literature?

Comment: Welcome Are to Physics SE. Please describe your search so far and how what you've found is insufficient.  For example, have you looked at the articles cited in the [relevant section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_wind#Velocity_and_density) of the solar wind Wikipedia article.

Comment: how about this and its multiple references https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.04261

Comment: Here are two that have a lot of good references:  https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018ApJS..236...41W/abstract and https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2021RvGeo..5900714W/abstract

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/527527/59023 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/695956/59023