# How can I determine sound speed of ions in plasma sheath

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, ions

Since the definition of sound speed, ($c_{s}$), in each ion s$th$ species ($is$) expressed that:

\begin{align*}
c_{s,is} = \sqrt{\frac{k(T_{e}+T_{is})}{m_{is}}}.
\end{align*}

How can we determine sound speed for multi-component plasma when the multi-component plasmas containing with $\text{e}^{-},\, \text{p}^{+}$, and $\text{Ar}^{+}$, and entering in the sheath region? Should it be a linear combination of each ion species for ion sound speed?

Answer (score 1):

The formal definition for the [speed of sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_sound) is given as:
$$
C_{s}^{2} = \frac{ \partial P }{ \partial \rho } \tag{0}
$$
where $P$ is the total thermal pressure and $\rho$ is the total mass density.  Note that [velocity moments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/218643/59023) are additive, so if you have a multi-species [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)), the total pressure and total mass density are given by:
$$
\begin{align}
  P & = \sum_{s} P_{s} \tag{1a} \\
  \rho & = \left( \frac{ \sum_{s} m_{s} \ n_{s}^{2} }{ \sum_{s} n_{s} } \right) \tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
where $n_{s}$ is the number density of species $s$ and $m_{s}$ is the mass of species $s$.  Note that mass density is not a velocity moment, number density is, thus why mass density does not add linearly.

In the case of a sound wave, one assumes that during the longitudinal and compressional oscillation of the particles, the dynamics are said to be adiabatic so the pressure of any given species goes as:
$$
P_{s} \propto \rho_{s}^{\gamma_{s}} \tag{2}
$$
where $\gamma_{s}$ is the [polytropic index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio) of species $s$.  In a weakly collisional plasma, each particle species can have a unique $\gamma_{s}$.  If the system is collisionally dominated (i.e., collision frequencies are comparable to the [cyclotron frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotron_resonance) and/or the [plasma frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation)), then the plasma will behave more like an ideal gas with a single $\gamma$.

Thus, the speed of sound will go to:
$$
C_{s}^{2} = \frac{ \sum_{s} \gamma_{s} \ P_{s} }{ \rho } \tag{3}
$$

If we further assume an ideal gas, we can say each pressure is roughly $n_{s} k_{B} T_{s}$, where $n_{s}$ is the number density of species $s$, $k_{B}$ is the Boltzmann constant, and $T_{s}$ is the temperature of species $s$.  The the sound speed will take the form of:
$$
C_{s}^{2} = \frac{ \sum_{s} \gamma_{s} \ n_{s} \ k_{B} \ T_{s} }{ \rho } \tag{4}
$$

In a two population plasma with quasi-neutrality satisfied, note that $n_{e} = n_{i} = n_{o}$ such that the right-hand side of Equation 1b simplifies to $n_{o} \sum_{s} m_{s}$.  If there are multiple ion species, then it remains in its less trivial form since $n_{i}$ would be the total ion density given by:
$$
n_{i} = \sum_{s} Z_{s} \ n_{s} \tag{5}
$$
where $Z_{s}$ is the charge state of species $s$.  It is still true that $n_{e} = n_{i}$ but note that $n_{e} \neq n_{i,j}$ where $j$ refers to the ion subpopulation (i.e., protons or argon ions in your example).